# Python Play Sound Easily

Tags: python, audio, jython, trigonometry

After literally months of research to find sound functionality as simple as on the 80s micros, I have finally found TygerJython (http://jython.tobiaskohn.ch/), which ALMOST does what I want except for some reason there is a short maximum duration for the playTone method, and I need drones for my sonic experiments. Could someone please give the very simplest, minimum-package-installing Python solution to produce what the following code is supposed to:

```
import math

def frange(start, stop, step):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step

melody = []        
for angle in frange(0, 4 * math.pi, 0.1):
    expr = 440**1+(100*math.sin(angle))
    melody.append(int(round(expr,0)))

v=50
playTone(440, v * len(melody),block=False) 
for f in melody:
    playTone(f,v)
```

Alternatively, clear instructions on how to modify TygerJython to alter the max duration for playTone.